# Are there any publications which would indicate that American journalists understand the concept of ‘auto-coup’ or ‘self-coup'?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions, american-english

On the 6th of January, 2021, and  in the United States, it appears that   we were in the midst of an armed insurrection that reached beyond the Capitol steps during sessions, penetrating even to chambers... an action which may have  been  encouraged tacitly in tweets  by a sitting lame-duck
US president
.

Shots were heard. The Senators were advised to hide under desks and wear gas masks..

That seems to be ***an attempted *self-coup*.***

Definition of ***self-coup***

> A self-coup, or autocoup (from the Spanish autogolpe), is a form of putsch or coup d'état in which a nation's leader, despite having come to power through legal means, dissolves or renders powerless the national legislature and unlawfully assumes extraordinary powers not granted under normal circumstances.

[-Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-coup)

A little background...

When German President Hindenburg died in 1933, Chancellor Hitler assumed the title of president, outlawed all other parties and became a dictator. He did this out of his long-declared personal sense of cultural victimization, and said he was ‘saving’ the country.

He was already in a position of power, but affected a type of take-over from within; this had become his avowed purpose after the failed putsch of 1923 and subsequent imprisonment for insurrection.

In 1991, President Serrano of Guatemala overthrew his own government in a move which was later termed *Serranazo* i.e. where *azo* indicates a blow (*coup*) or strike. I remember waking up early on May 25th to the sounds of APCs and tanks taking up position in the streets in front of my house...

In Latin-America, we call this type of political move an [*auto-golpe*,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-coup) similar to an *auto-gol* in football (soccer for Americans)

As far as I know, and with the possible exception of the turbulent times after  US Civil War, there has never been any attempt at declaring [martial law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martial_law_in_the_United_States) to counter a free and fair election in the United States.

It would seem to fly in the face of the face  of American democracy...

---

Right now in the United States, citizens are wondering if there is a possible *coup d’état* occurring in the country.

> …former national security adviser Michael Flynn had shared a petition that called for martial law. He then retweeted the same account which suggested that Trump should declare martial law.
> "I don't know who needs to hear this," the account said, "But calling for martial law is not a bad idea when there is an attempted coup against the president and this country happening right now."

[CNN](https://edition.cnn.com/2020/12/04/politics/trump-nominee-pentagon-martial-law/index.html)

---

Martial law to counter politically unacceptable election results is essentially a...

[Self-coup or auto-coup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-coup)

---

Most usages of the terms go to [reports of politics in Latin America,](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22self%20coup%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2012,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en) and so seem to be calques.

[Some political rags](https://www.thenation.com/article/society/trump-coup-elections-gop/) still call it a *coup d’état* and do not seem to use the other more descriptive terminology.

I have no doubt that most Americans recognize ***coup d’état***...

...but is the concept behind ***auto-coup***, or ***self-coup*** dealt with in American publications? Is it a recognizable term in US politics?

---

Comment: Not if you said it out loud. In fact, not even if you whispered it.

Comment: Usage of *coup d’etat vs self-coup and auto-coup*  in AmE may suggest that usage of the latter is quite uncommon. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=self-coup%2Cauto-coup%2Ccoup+d%E2%80%99etat&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cself%20-%20coup%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cauto%20-%20coup%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccoup%20d%27%20etat%3B%2Cc0

Comment: How can you assess if a term, any term , is  properly understood by average American? Evidence suggested by Google Books shows that the terms (self-coup and auto-coup) are uncommon in AmE, so we can assume average American is supposedly unfamiliar with them. Other than that you have to rest on anecdotal evidence.

Comment: @user121863 OK..I will try to re-phrase the Q...the problem is that it is an unrecognized term in US politics Lemme think on it..

Comment: There are a lot of people who would interpret "self-coup" as "self-quarantine".

Comment: I agree: the two terms *auto-coup* and *self-coup* are unknown in the US

Comment: @Cascabel, the problem with the question is not that it's off topic, but that it has a simple answer, which is not really worth posting as an answer: neither term is commonly used in the United States, so there is no **established** way in which an **average** person there understands them. Any published occurrences of either of these terms in the United States are likely to be in the publications that are read by a small number of people people with highly specialised interests.

Comment: @jsw29 Txs...That's what I thought..I was just trying to verify it. It seems that the expression  has only come into usage in English since the 60s, and most citations are about Latin American politics. Sad that we have come to this point where US politics are looking like banana republic stuff, and I say that seriously: I have lived in a banana republic for over 30 years and seen this shit happen. If you don't mind, I may quote you, along with some of the other users posting comments.

Comment: Your question would probably be more suitable on SE Politics. It appears to me that you are looking more for comments on possible coups in the US rather than its linguistic relevance.

Comment: @user121863 Sorry to say that I have pretty much given up on those guys...they seem to be an incestuous lot, and unwelcoming to newer users. That said, I will give it a shot in a day or 2.

Comment: Sorry to break this to you, but the average American may not even know how their government is _meant_ to work, much less how it _doesn't_ work.

Comment: @Conrado Actually, that is not news for me. It is tragic how everyday Americans are accepting the possibility of over-turning election results...and installing a fascist regime.

Comment: The USA has never experienced a successful, or even an attempted, "auto-coup" since its founding. Since "auto-coup" is just a more specific type of coup, rather than an altogether different concept, there's not really a pressing need for the new term, and people just say "coup" here in the USA. To my ears, actually, "auto-coup" implies **more** legitimacy on the part of the autocrat than in a regular coup, and legitimacy is not something I'm willing to grant Trump's last-ditch fart (literally: https://defector.com/did-donald-trump-fart-while-attempting-to-commit-election-fraud/) of a coup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***'Auto-coup', (or self-coup) is understood   by  journalists and scholars who have studied political events in ‘third-world’ countries***

---

**"Make no mistake: Trump is trying to pull off a Latin American-style ‘self-coup’"**

[-by Andres Oppenheimer *Miami Herald*](https://www.miamiherald.com/news/local/news-columns-blogs/andres-oppenheimer/article248321135.html)

NB: Posted 1 hour after the events of 1/6/2021 in D.C. (not so coincidentally with the re-opening of this post…)

> What happened Wednesday in Washington, D.C. — President Trump encouraging his mob of minions to take to the streets to overturn the results of an election he lost, before telling them to go home — is a classic example of a Latin American ***auto-golpe***, or ***self-coup***.

> I have seen many ***auto-golpes*** in Latin America while writing about the region in recent decades, most recently in Bolivia, in 2019.
> Trump has been a disgrace to America, and to the world. Until now, coup attempts were a Latin American and African phenomenon. Now, thanks to Trump, they are part of America’s reality.

---

[From MSNBC](https://www.rawstory.com/josh-hawley-election-black-vote/) as reported by RawPolitics.com

> Sen. Josh Hawley (R-MO) is taking up the attempt to overthrow the 2020 election from the U.S. Senate while Rep. Mo Brooks (R-AL) plans to do it in the House. [Yale historian and expert on authoritarianism, Timothy Snyder,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timothy_D._Snyder) explained on MSNBC Wednesday that it wouldn't be hyperbolic to call it an attempted coup d'etat.

> "I think there is no problem at all calling this a coup or a ***self-coup*** or an attempted coup," Snyder explained. "The only thing which is a little bit different about this, historically speaking, is how much of it Mr. Trump broadcast in advance. He spent six or seven months before November telling us how he would try to throw the election after November, and he did basically all the things he said he was going to do. I mean, for people who think the military has to be involved, it's not for lack of trying."

---

[by  Zenep Zufecki  *The Atlantic*](https://www.theatlantic.com/ideas/archive/2020/12/trumps-farcical-inept-and-deadly-serious-coup-attempt/617309/)

“In political science, the term coup refers to the illegitimate overthrow of a sitting government—usually through violence or the threat of violence. The technical term for attempting to stay in power illegitimately—such as after losing an election—is ***self-coup*** or ***autocoup***, sometimes *autogolpe.*”

**IMOH...The complete text of the Atlantic article is an eye-opener for most Americans, and should be read in its entirety.**

---

[Wikipedia has a new entry under the Header of Self-Coup or Auto-Coup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-coup)

> **Notable self-coups and attempts**:
> United States: President Donald Trump (November 2020–January 2021) (failed)

Comment: It would be the ultimate irony if Trump needs to look for asylum in one of those "shithole" countries he despises  to escape justice in the US...